# iPhone converts dates on my website into phone numbers — how can I prevent this?

Tags: iphone, html, web

Recently I checked my website in iPhone and I discovered that the iPhone **sometimes** convert dates or anything similiar to phone numbers.

What does it mean? Let’s say I’ve got, somewhere on my website, the following line:

`<font style="color:red;font-size:40px;">bla bla bla 19/03/2011</font>`

The iPhone converts it to a phone number — the color become black and the font size become small (like 12px).

How can I disable it? What do I need to add to my website in order to prevent the conversion?

I can manipulate it so it won’t convert it into phone number - for example by adding '-' before the date, but I dont want to do it that way.

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: The first time I've come across that, +1! =)

Comment: Thank you. this is exactly what I was looking for! I didnt know what to write in google to find it.